# PrintWindow on inactive desktop in Windows 10

Tags: c++, c, windows-10

So, I've run into a problem while trying to take a picture of a window located in an inactive desktop using the PrintWindow API and it is starting to get on my nerves.

The problem is that with a specific window, even though PrintWindow succeeds and I get the image of the window I want, that image is always an outdated copy of the last time the desktop was active. At first I thought the window was not receiving any input, but after some checking I noticed that it still receives and processes input, but does not render any changes until its desktop gets activated again. I tested in Windows 7 and 10, and that only happens in Windows 10.

After some more checking, I found out that the main window in fact updates itself just as expected and it is its child, which covers all the client area of the main window, who is to blame. The 2 windows were created with the following styles:

**Class Styles:** 0x00000003 = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW

**Parent Extended Styles**: 0x00000000

**Parent Standard Styles**: 0x96000000 = WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS

**Child Extended Styles**: 0x00000020 = WS_EX_TRANSPARENT

**Child Standard Styles**: 0x56300000 = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL

I have already tried an absolutely uncountable amount of things trying to get this problem solved, and I've searched the web extensively, all to no avail. I am so frustrated that I am well ready to give up if noone can at least come up with an explanation for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "inactive desktop"?

Comment: Not enough programmers write a message handler for WM_PRINTCLIENT.  Easy to do, they just don't think of it.  That makes it hard to implement PrintWindow() correctly.  The workaround is undocumented, but I'd imagine that the backing bitmap that Aero creates would be useful.  With the hangup that it no longer gets updated when the desktop is not active.  Something like that.

Comment: @VTT A desktop that is not the one who is currently visible to the user.

Comment: Are you talking about ["virtual desktops" introduced in Windows 10](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/04/16/virtual-desktops-in-windows-10-the-power-of-windowsmultiplied/)?

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean by "the backing bitmap that Aero creates"? My next try would be to implement my own WM_PRINT/WM_PRINTCLIENT on behalf of the window, even though I'm not completely familiar of how this is done and also because I think thats not the problem here, as all the windows that do not process PrintWindow correctly normally just return an empty bitmap instead of an outdated one.

Comment: @VTT Kind of. These were implemented in Windows 10, but multiple desktop functionality exists since XP or so.

Comment: The difference between virtual desktops in Windows 10 and extra desktops existing prior to it are that virtual desktops are managed by DWM that draw or skips window without actually switching desktop Also one can not rely on aero bitmap as DWM is not required to keep it (and it may be still outdated). Anyway, window not redrawing itself when it is not visible makes perfect sense, and is a recommended behavior according to guidelines.

Comment: @VTT The fact is that it works for most windows with few exceptions, being this specific window the only one to show that kind of behavior and only in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not render windows that are not visible. You are getting the current image, which is the same image you would get when getting the little preview window when hovering over the task bar icon.
Without the program itself explicitly calling the render function the window will not update. It's not going to be possible to get a screenshot of how the window would currently look if it updated.

Comment: Other windows in the same desktop get rendered just as normal with PrintWindow and even the same window gets rendered in Windows 7. It is a Windows 10 only problem.

Comment: That surprises me. I thought it was expected behavior that the covered window doesn't get updated at all.

Comment: I've also tried forcing the window to repaint using several different methods, but all I managed to do is erase the contents of the window, which don't get redrawn until the desktop is reactivated.